# c# Web api nested json field change dynamically

Tags: c#, json, api

I need to return a json object from my web api. The problem is there is a nested object. in that object column name changed dynamically and also nested object has only cursive bracket. Sample json given below. Any one know how to solve this issue please help.

```
[

   {

      src: 'https://www.test.com/line.jpg',

      screen: 'PLAYLIST_SCREEN',

      data: {

        playlist_id: '751becbe-5546-4728-8738-e96238be4749'

      }

    },

    {

      src: 'https://www.test.com/linet-2.jpg',

      screen: 'VIDEO_SCREEN',

      data: {

        video_id: '40541a11-e29d-4852-91c8-c2aac76d64c9'

      }

    },

    {

      src: 'https://www.test.com/line_3xl.jpg?impolicy=HomeHero',

      screen: 'SEARCH_SCREEN',

      data: {

        query: 'برنامج صباح الخير يا كويت'

      }

    }

]
```

Comment: Nested objects are not a problem for JSON. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Is data a C# object that is being converted to JSON? Or are you just trying to create a JSON response from some data source?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `data` is coming from a C# object, you can use this attribute to skip serialization of any properties that are null:

```
[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
```

Here is an example of what data might look like in C#:

```
public class data
{
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    [JsonPropertyName("playlist_id")]
    public string? PlaylistId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    [JsonPropertyName("video_id")]
    public string? VideoId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    [JsonPropertyName("query")]
    public string? Query { get; set; }
};
```

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-5-0) has more examples of usage.